# saveFileDialog не меняет каталог

Tags: c#

Всем привет,
Вызываю saveFileDialog, он открывается в каталоге запуска программы, я хожу по другим каталогам, выбираю, в какой сохранить, сохраняю - но файл все равно оказывается в начальном каталоге.
Как его заставить сохранять в выбранный мной каталог?

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить в вопрос ваш код (для этого нажмите [edit])

Comment: Про что речь, Winforms? Добавьте соответствующую метку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно где-то хранить путь. Пусть будет string CurrentPath.
После создания saveFileDialog1 запишите в InitialDirectory этот путь. Первый раз будет пустая строка.

```
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = CurrentPath;
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    -- какой-то ваш код--
    CurrentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName);    
}
```

Теперь будет открываться последний каталог, который открывали.

Comment: Спасибо.
А если приложение перенесут (скопируют в другую папку на другом компе) - какой каталог будет открываться?

Comment: Это зависит от того, где вы будете хранить CurrentPath. Если например в текстовом файле в начальном каталоге - он перенесется вместе с приложением и будет указывать неизвестно куда. Соответственно возникнет ошибка, которую нужно обрабатывать. Хранение параметров приложения - это отдельная большая тема.

Answer (score 0):

Для примера возьмем Net 7, WinForms приложение и добавим туда 1 кнопку для сохранения.
Выбор имени файла и его расширение действительно происходит через `SaveFileDialog`.
При нажатии на кнопку будем показывать пользователю окно выбора пути и дадим ему возможность назвать файл так, как ему нужно.

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

    var showResult = sfd.ShowDialog();

    if (showResult != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return; //Пользователь закрыл окно сохранения или отменил операцию
    }

    var selectedPath = sfd.FileName;

    File.WriteAllText(selectedPath, "Hello, Stack!");

    MessageBox.Show($"Файл сохранен: {selectedPath}");
}
```

Обратите внимание, что `ShowDialog` вернет `DialogResult`, результат которого мы хотим видеть как `DialogResult.Ok`, остальные операции (пользователь закрыл окно на крестик, нажал кнопку "Отмена" и пр.) нас не интересуют и мы можем их не обрабатывать.
В итоге выбранный путь пользователя будет находиться в переменной FileName (обратите внимание, что есть еще [FileNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), куда указываются имена нескольких файлов, если у вас предусмотрено сохранение сразу нескольких файлов).